# How to check if a file's size is greater than a certain value in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

How do I achieve the following goal:

- I need to check the size of a file
- Then compare this file size to a fixed number using an *if* condition and corresponding conditional statement

So far, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# File to consider
FILENAME=./testfile.txt

# MAXSIZE is 5 MB
MAXSIZE = 500000

# Get file size
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
# Checkpoint
echo "Size of $FILENAME = $FILESIZE bytes."

# The following doesn't work
if [ (( $FILESIZE > MAXSIZE)) ]; then
    echo "nope"
else
    echo "fine"
fi
```

---

With this code, I can get the file name in the variable $FILESIZE, but I am unable to compare it with a fixed integer value.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=./testfile.txt
maxsize=5
filesize=$(stat -c%s "$filename")
echo "Size of $filename = $filesize bytes."

if (( filesize > maxsize )); then
    echo "nope"
else
    echo "fine"
fi
```

Comment: `if [ (( $FILESIZE > MAXSIZE)) ];` -> `if (( FILESIZE > MAXSIZE ));` The arithmetic operators can serve as a conditional expression. (you don't need the `$` within `((...))`)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A couple of syntactic issues.

1. The variable definitions in Bash do not take spaces. It should have been `MAXSIZE=500000`, without spaces.
2. The way comparison operation is done is incorrect. Instead of `if [ (( $FILESIZE > MAXSIZE)) ];`, you could very well use Bash’s own arithmetic operator alone and skip the `[` operator to just `if (( FILESIZE > MAXSIZE)); then`

If you are worried about syntax issues in your script, use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to syntax check your scripts and fix the errors as seen from it.

---

As a general coding practice, use *lowercase* user-defined variables in Bash to avoid confusing them with the special environment variables which are interpreted for different purposes by the shell (e.g., `$HOME` and `$SHELL`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`find`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) command to accomplish this as well. See the below examples.

You can change the *[stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)* command for any command you need.

```
ls -lh test.txt

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25M Jan 20 19:36 test.txt


find ~/test.txt -size 25M -exec stat '{}' \;

  File: '/root/test.txt'
  Size: 26214400        Blocks: 51200      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe04h/65028d    Inode: 402704      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-01-20 19:36:51.222371293 +0000
Modify: 2022-01-20 19:36:51.242373113 +0000
Change: 2022-01-20 19:36:51.242373113 +0000
 Birth: -
```

If the file does not have the size you are looking for, it won't do anything.

```
find ~/test.txt -size 99M -exec true \;
```

Comment: you can say +99M to find files equal to/larger than 99M, likewise -99M for smaller than...